# How to create and open a jupyter notebook ipynb file directly from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook

The command `jupyter notebook` will open the Jupyter directory tree page where you can create a ipynb file.

Is there a way to skip that page and create and open the ipynb file directly on the browser?

I was thinking something like jupyter notebook mynotebook.ipynb

Answer (score 15):

Open notebook in browser

```
jupyter notebook <notebook>.ipynb
```

Create empty, minimal notebook:

```
"""create-notebook.py
   Creates a minimal jupyter notebook (.ipynb)
   Usage: create-notebook <notebook>
"""
import sys
from notebook import transutils as _
from notebook.services.contents.filemanager import FileContentsManager as FCM

try:
    notebook_fname = sys.argv[1].strip('.ipynb')
except IndexError:
    print("Usage: create-notebook <notebook>")
    exit()

notebook_fname += '.ipynb'  # ensure .ipynb suffix is added
FCM().new(path=notebook_fname)
```

Alias create-notebook script:

```
alias create-notebook='python $(pwd)/create-notebook.py'
```

## Putting it all together

`create-notebook my_notebook && jupyter notebook my_notebook.ipynb`

Comment: `jupyter notebook <notebook>.ipynb` as well as `jupyter notebook <path/to>/<notebook>.ipynb` appear (under Linux at least) to have the very unfortunate side-effect of pinning the 'root' of the file tree to the directory containing `<notebook>.ipynb`, making it impossible to open notebooks in directories other than those which are direct descendants of that directory, either from the commandline or by opening the file browser by clicking on the Jupyter logo in the top left of the notebook.

Answer (score 14):

This can't be the most desirable method. Maybe there's an option native to Jupyter or the [extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions), but I haven't come across one, nor have I come across the need to do this. The documentation suggests the developers are encouraging users to land at the dashboard.

Start with an empty notebook `Untitled.ipynb`. To generate it, save the default file that is created when you create a new notebook from the jupyter dashboard. This empty notebook will be used as a template for creating new, empty notebooks at the command line. The contents of `Untitled.ipynb` for me, jupyter version 4.4.0, look like this:

```
$ cat Untitled.ipynb
{
 "cells": [],
 "metadata": {},
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

The file contains the bare minimum needed to launch a notebook using `jupyter notebook Untitled.ipynb` (and eventually `mynotebook.ipynb`), any less and it will raise a `NotJSONError`. You can add some metadata to the template if you want to include a default kernel.

From here, use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to open a new, empty notebook from the command line where `Untitled.ipynb` is the path to the template notebook created above and `mynotebook.ipynb` is the name of the notebook you wish to create:

```
$ jupyter notebook $(cat Untitled.ipynb >mynotebook.ipynb && echo mynotebook.ipynb)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I just made a minor mod, which is to use a heredoc: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/355648ee4f0644e26f1821db9de669ff)

Comment: As for Jupyter nbformat v4, that keys are the minimum schema as mentioned in the code [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/blob/7e28474d618baf9889e609bcbfe64263337702e5/nbformat/v4/nbformat.v4.schema.json#L6).

Answer (score 8):

You may try below command.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute mynotebook.ipynb
```

According to [Jupyter nbconvert manual](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#notebook-and-preprocessors) below, `nbconvert` with `--execute` command supports running a notebook.

[image]
Hope it works for you.

Comment: That didn't work. I get `[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern u'mynotebook.ipynb' matched no files This application is used to convert notebook files (*.ipynb) to various other formats.` and a long list of messages following that.

Comment: @multigoodverse It seems that the WARNING tells no ipynb file is found. Could you use absolute path to specific mynotebook.ipynb?

Comment: I get the sane thing using the absolute path.

Comment: @multigoodverse if the notebook file path and/or filename include accented characters (`ã`, `í`, etc.), that might be the cause of problem. Check [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5530) if it helps.

Comment: It doesn't create a new notebook! Opens an existing one.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same pain point and created `nbplot` to fix it: https://github.com/nburrus/nbplot . It was designed to quickly plot files in a notebook from the command line, but overall it's just a tiny tool to generate notebooks from templates and open them in the browser. Here is how you would use it with the included empty template to answer your question:

```
pip3 install --upgrade nbplot
nbplot -t empty -o mynotebook.ipynb
```

It will try to be smart about reusing existing notebook servers instead of always starting a new one, and it's easy to add custom notebook templates to `~/.nbplot/` if you don't want to start with an empty notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new notebook from the command line using `jupytext`:

```sh
# create python file
touch foo.py

# add kernel information
jupytext --set-kernel - foo.py

# convert to notebook
jupytext --to notebook foo.py

# open in browser
jupyter notebook foo.ipynb
```

https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html

---

These commands could be wrapped in a shell script named something like `jupyinit`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Create a new Jupyter notebook from the command line
# 
# Examples
# jupyinit env_name py_file.py py_file.ipynb

touch $2
jupytext --set-kernel $1 $2
jupytext --to notebook --execute $2
jupytext --set-formats ipynb,py $3
```

The OP's example could then be created with:

`$ jupyinit myenv mynotebook.py mynotebook.ipynb`

Comment: this was really valuable - but the "--set-kernel" feature is no longer needed

Comment: So every time I updated `mynotebook.py` I would have to run the `jupyinit ...` again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python package [`jnb`](https://github.com/Udesh-Ranjan/jnb/blob/main/README.md) for this task it will create a new Python notebook with the specified **name** and **location**.

### Installation

```
python -m pip install jnb
```

### Usage

```
python -m jnb -c ~/Documents/.../Learning_Pandas_And_Numpy.ipynb
```

and the above command will create a new *Jupiter notebook*.

[Here](https://github.com/Udesh-Ranjan/jnb/blob/main/README.md) is the official documentation for the `jnb` package.

Answer (score -1):

Jupyter will start running on Tornado server on localhost. The link is something like http://localhost/Tree 
When you open a notebook, this is done in another page. You can try to write a batch script to call kupyter notebok, then call your browser with the address to your notebook. I take it that if the notebook doesn't exist, is not created, then it will not work (the page is note created, it cannot be opened).